# Getting unique values in python using List Comprehension technique

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to get the values that appear in one of the lists but not in the others. I even tried  using '<>', it says invalid syntax. I am trying using list comprehensions.

```
com_list = []
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
b1 = [6,4,2,1]
come_list = [a for a in a1 for b in b1 if a != b ]
```

Output:
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]

My expected output would be `[3, 5, 6]

Comment: `come_list = a1 + [x for x in b1 if x not in a1]`

Comment: i'm guessing this is for learning purpose, cos sets could easily take care of this

Comment: "unqiue values between the 2 lists" is unclear. Do you want values that only appear in one of the lists, the set of all values... Please clarify and add your expected output.

Comment: I  could easliy get the unique values using this com_list = []
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
b1 = [6,4,2,1]
come_list = [a for a in a1 for b in b1 if a==b ] I want to get non-matching values between these two lists. eg : 3,5,6 are the non-matching values between these two lists.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference), you can do:

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
b1 = [6,4,2,1]

set(a1).symmetric_difference(b1)
# {3, 5, 6}
```

which you can also write as:

```
set(a1) ^ set(b1)
```

If you really want a list in the end, just convert it:

```
list(set(a1) ^ set(b1))
# [3, 5, 6]
```

a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
b1 = [6,4,2,1]

---

If you really want to do that using list comprehensions, well, here it is, but it's really not the right thing to do here.

A totally inefficient version:

```
# Don't do that !

sym_diff = [x for x in a1+b1 if x in a1 and x not in b1 or x in b1 and x not in a1]
print(sym_diff)

# [3, 5, 6]
```

It would be a bit better using sets to test membership efficiently:

```
# Don't do that either

a1 = set([1,2,3,4,5])
b1 = set([6,4,2,1])

sym_diff = [x for x in a1|b1 if x in a1 and x not in b1 or x in b1 and x not in a1]
print(sym_diff)

# [3, 5, 6]
```

But if you start using sets, which is the right thing to do here, use them all the way properly and use symmetric_difference.

Comment: Yes I even i tried and got the answer, but my point is I want to get the same output using List Comprehension technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
come_list =[i for i in list((set(a1) - set(b1))) + list((set(b1) - set(a1)))]
print(come_list)
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 6]
```

This new list contains all unique numbers for both of the lists together.
the problem with this line `come_list = [a for a in a1 for b in b1 if a != b ]` is that the items iterating over each item in the first list over all the items in the second list to check if it's inited but it's not giving unique numbers between both.

Comment: even simple `list(set(a1+b1))`

Comment: You are right. it requests to be with using List Comprehension technique

Comment: This helps, what if I want to get non-matching values from the 2 lists?....

Comment: You are doing [i for i in set(a1) - set(b1)]

Comment: Your  code doesn't output what you say it does, but `[3, 5]`. It's always better to test it! ;)

Comment: Tnx for the note updated the code according to the note.